# RecurrenceTable: numercial exception

Tags: recursion, vector-calculus

When I added vector b into expression, it returned with RecurrenceTable::excptn: Value {2/3,-(1/3),2/3,-(1/3)} is a numerical exception.

```
A = {{2, 0}, {0, 4}}; b = {0, 0}; x0 = {2, 1};
RecurrenceTable[{x[k + 1] == x[k] - Norm[A.x[k] + b]^2/((A.x[k] + b).A.(A.x[k] +b))*(A.x[k] + b) , x[0] == {2, 1}}, x, {k, 0, 20}]
```

It works fine without adding b. How to make it work without removing b?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually generate the table from the recurrence equation.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

A = {{2, 0}, {0, 4}}; b = {0, 0}; x0 = {2, 1};

x[0] = x0;

x[k_Integer?Positive] := x[k] =
  x[k - 1] - 
   Norm[A.x[k - 1] + b]^2/((A.x[k - 1] + b).A.(A.x[k - 1] + b))*(A.x[k - 1] + 
      b)

(table = x /@ Range[0, 20]) // Column
```

[image]

The closed-form solution is

```
sol[k_Integer] = Simplify[FindSequenceFunction[
     Transpose[{Range[0, 20], table[[All, #]]}], k] & /@
   {1, 2}]

(* {2 3^-k, (-(1/3))^k} *)

(sol /@ Range[0, 20]) == table

(* True *)
```